# After re-install Office XP , starting of any office program asks for product key

Tags: windows-xp

I reinstalled Windows XP and then Office XP on the PC. When I started after this any office program (Word, Excel) I asked got window asking for product key:

The question is

1. Is there some BIOS setting(s) changed by first installation of Office XP - if so it will be very helpful to know which one
2. Are there registry key(s) which affect on asking for product key, if so, which one? I found similar ones for later versions of office (2007, 2003) but did not found for office XP

I know that there already were questions about similar issues but I did not found suitable answer.

Comment: If there is a "Starter" or other version of office installed besides office XP, uninstall them.

Comment: Change Office XP key...http://www.petri.co.il/change_office_xp_cd_key.htm

Answer (score 1):

So why don't you just give it the key?  A reinstall of XP (OS) would have wiped your entire registry and rebuilding it from scratch sounds ... well, painful at best.

Comment: Thanks for reply 
I can give , but until now the key was required only for setup only

Comment: This is the setup.

Comment: Like ZippyV says, this is the setup phase.  After you give it the key (once) it should shut up and work.  IF it doesn't then keep posting updates here...